# how to hide links in discord.js

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I've got this code

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === `L!succ`) {
    // message goes below!
        message.channel.send('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/525096492470370314/653855352877481984/8742_Succ.gif');
        }
});
```

It's good and all but I wanna hide the url
I've tried the following

```
client.on('message', message => {
    // If the message is '!rip'
    if (message.content === '!rip') {
    // Create the attachment using MessageAttachment
    const attachment = new MessageAttachment('https://i.imgur.com/w3duR07.png');
    // Send the attachment in the message channel
    message.channel.send(attachment);
    }
});
```

(so trying to attach it)
So I want to make the link disappear and just make it become just the gif itself hopefully someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WITH Attachment as file**

```
client.on('message', message => {
    // If the message is '!rip'
    if (message.content === '!rip') {
        // Create the attachment using Attachment
        const attachment = new Attachment('https://i.imgur.com/w3duR07.png');
        // Send the attachment in the message channel
        message.channel.send(attachment);
    }
});
```

**WITH Embeded IMAGE**

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!rip') {
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        embed.setImage('https://i.imgur.com/w3duR07.png')
    message.channel.send(embed);
    }
});
```

Comment: actually ive got one more for you with this code `client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!rip') {
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        embed.setImage('https://i.imgur.com/w3duR07.png')
    message.channel.send(embed);
    }
}); ` how would i go about adding in words above the gif?

Comment: You can use [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) as variant

Comment: You can check manual of this module. There is a fairly detailed description of image editing.

Comment: hey cipher i'ved seemed to have found another way of doing what i asked above

Comment: `});
client.on('message', message => {
 if (message.content.startsWith('L!spank')) {
  let targetMember = message.mentions.members.first();
  if (!targetMember) return message.reply('you need to tag a user in order to spank them!!');
  // message goes below!
  message.channel.send(` ${targetMember.user}, you just got spanked!!`);
  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  embed.setImage('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/580581441122074646/662110318377435136/anime-spanking-gif-3.gif')
  message.channel.send(embed);
 }
});`

Comment: Hey, whats the problem ?

Comment: So some of the cmd can’t load the embedded picture

Comment: Yes it does and the other code that uses the same code but actually works ;-;

Comment: So problem in the module, or before thats part of code, the questions asked in the comments are hard to understand because code structuring and description are poor (due to stackoverflow formatting)

Comment: So I believe it’s the module tho doe to the error codes

Answer (score 1):

Its now like this:

```
client.on("message", msg => {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    attachment.setImage("Your URL");
    msg.reply(embed);
});
```

The RichEmbed is not available anymore